# Unix cut operation

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a string like this:

```
uid=2560(jdihenia) gid=1000(undergrad)
```

I want to just get the `undergrad` part in to a variable name var1. So I used a command

```
var1=`echo "uid=2560(jdihenia) gid=1000(undergrad)" | cut -d "(" -f 3`
```

but this will assign the value `undergrad)` in to var1. Can you please tell me how can I get just the `undergrad` part in to the variable var1?

Comment: careful with those back ticks. I'd recommend you use `$()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the literal text "undergrad" in the brackets, this should work:

```
cut -d "(" -f 2 <text> | cut -d ")" -f 1
```

or equivalently

```
echo <text> | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. var1=`echo <text> | cut -d "(" -f 3 | cut -d ")" -f 1` worked well.

Answer (score 3):

If this string comes from `id`, then you can just call `id -gn` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
var1=$(cmd |sed 's/.*(\([^)]*\))/\1/')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var1="uid=2560(jdihenia) gid=1000(undergrad)"
var1=${var1#*\(*\(}
var1=${var1%%\)*}
```

Comment: Shorter: `var1=${var1##*\(}` and `var1=${var1%)*}`.

Comment: @Dennis, escaping the parentheses is required by the POSIX standard, by ksh (both ksh93 and mksh; the parentheses are part of an extended pattern matching notation) and by bash if `shopt -s extglob` is in effect. It appears to work in most other shells.

Comment: I see no ill effects, at least in these circumstances, with `extglob` in Bash.

Answer (score 2):

`echo "$str" | awk -F'[()]' '{print $4}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
var1=$( echo "uid=2560(jdihenia) gid=1000(undergrad)" | grep -Po 'gid=.*\(\K.*(?=\))')
```